# ArcGIS Pro Legend patch and layer name not center aligned

Tags: arcgis-pro, legend

I have some issues with my legend in Pro, where some patches and their layer names are aligned centrally, but others are aligned to the bottom of the patch. I can't seem to make sense of it or find a setting that changes it, only the distance between patch and layer name, not vertically.

[image]

Look at the differences between the "Community Forest" and the "Mining Concession".

Answer (score 1):

You can change the vertical alignment of the text in the 'Position' section of the text symbol editor:

[image: Vertical alignment example image]